# Download file from ftp using angular 5+?

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, download, ftp

I'm trying to use the npm library called ftp-client (https://www.npmjs.com/package/ftp-client) to download a simple image from my ftp server in my Angular 5 application. I copy-pasted the example but it does not seem to be working, I see this error in the console:
[image]

The code is:

```
var ftpClient = require('../../../../../node_modules/ftp-client'),
config = {
  host: 'ftp://myhost.com',
  port: 21,
  user: 'admin',
  password: 'admin'
},
options = {
    logging: 'basic'
},
client = new ftpClient(config, options);
client.connect(function (){
  client.download('/images/no-img.jpg', 'test/', {
      overwrite: 'all'
  }, function (result) {
      console.log(result);
  });
});
```

Just in case, ng -v output is:

```
Angular CLI: 1.7.4
Node: 8.11.1
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 5.2.11
```

What do you think it can be?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with typescript notation

you should use :

```
import * as ftpClient from 'ftp-client';
```

instead of :

```
var ftpClient = require('../../../../../node_modules/ftp-client'),
```

Comment: Can we upload too directly from angular using ftp-client?