# "Module not found: Error: Can't resolve" errors

Tags: angular, ssh2-sftp-client

I am trying to use `ssh2-sftp-client` package 5.3.1 version with `Angular 9.0.4` but getting so many errors like;

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/ssh2-sftp-client/lib/http-agents.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'https' in 'C:\workspace\myProject\node_modules\ssh2-sftp-client\lib'
```

and

```
   ERROR in ./node_modules/ssh2-sftp-client/lib/agent.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\workspace\myProject\node_modules\ssh2-sftp-client\lib'
```

I did `npm i ssh2-sftp-client` and imported to class like this;

```
import SFTPClient from "ssh2-sftp-client";
```

Comment: README states ssh2-sftp-clien is an SFTP client for node.js (not for web browers)

Comment: can not I use in angular project ?

Comment: I tried to use another package but same error. 
  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52601103/download-file-from-ftp-using-angular-5

Comment: You cannot use libraries where were only built for node.js in angular. `ftp-client` is also node.js only library

Comment: @Prabh how can I download ftp file with angular 9, why I can't find any good source ?

Comment: So as I figured, you can't download ftp files from client side.